# Force limit parameter to be set in ansible

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to force commands `ansible-playbook`, `ansible-variable`, etc... to be executed with a `--limit` option (otherwise to deny it) ?

I discovered that, on a cluster it can easily run a playbook to all nodes if you mistakenly run it without limit, I'd like to prevent it from ansible users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the opposite of the task I've solved recently. My goal was to detect there is a `--limit` and to skip some plays.

https://medium.com/opsops/how-to-detect-if-ansible-is-run-with-limit-5ddb8d3bd145

In your case you can check this in the play and fail if it "full run":

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
         full_run: '{{play_hosts == groups.all}}'
    - fail:
        msg: 'Use --limit, Luke!'
      when: full_run
```

You can use a different group instead of `all`, of course (change it in both `hosts` and `set_fact` lines).

Answer (score 8):

Use the `ansible_limit` variable (added in ansible 2.5). You can test like this:

```
tasks:
  - fail:
      msg: "you must use -l or --limit"
    when: ansible_limit is not defined
    run_once: true
```

Comment: This works (so +1), but it annoyingly displays "skipping [myfirsthost]" when run with a limit. I've tried adding `delegate_to: localhost`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I admit this is cosmetic. Anyone know how to "fix" this?

Comment: adding a `- name: Check limit` line above `fail:` avoids a task entitled "fail", which is a little less scary to the casual observer. Remember to remove the `-` in `- fail:` should you choose to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the [assert module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html).

I like to do this in a separate play, at the start of the playbook, with fact gathering disabled. That way, the playbook fails instantly if the limit is not specified.

```ansible
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: assert limit
    run_once: yes
    assert:
      that:
      - 'ansible_limit is defined'
      fail_msg: Playbook must be run with a limit (normally staging or production)
      quiet: yes
```

When a limit is not set, you get:

```
$ ansible-playbook site.yaml 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [assert limit] ************************************************************
fatal: [host1.example.net]: FAILED! => {"assertion": "ansible_limit is defined", "changed": false, "evaluated_to": false, "msg": "Playbook must be run with a limit (normally staging or production)"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
host1.example.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And when a limit is set, you get:

```
$ ansible-playbook -l staging site.yaml 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [assert limit] ************************************************************
ok: [host1.example.com]

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

[... etc ...]
```

Functionally this is very similar to using the `fail` module, guarded with `when`. The difference is that the `assert` task itself is responsible for checking the assertions, therefore if the assertions pass, the task succeeds. When using the `fail` module, if the `when` condition fails, the task is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way in a task:

```
$ cat exit-if-no-limit.yml
---
  - name: Verifying that a limit is set
    fail:
      msg: 'This playbook cannot be run with no limit'
    run_once: true
    when: ansible_limit is not defined

  - debug:
      msg: Limit is {{ ansible_limit }}, let's continue
    run_once: true
    when: ansible_limit is defined
```

Which I include in my playbooks when I need to disallow them to run on all the hosts:

```
- include_role:
    name: myrole
    tasks_from: "{{ item }}.yml"
  loop:
  - exit-if-no-limit
  - something
  - something_else
```

Easy to reuse when needed. It works like that:

```
TASK [myrole: Verifying that a limit is set] 
fatal: [ahost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "This playbook cannot be run with no limit"}
```

or

```
TASK [myrole: debug] 
ok: [anotherhost] => {
    "msg": "Limit is anotherhost, let's continue"
}
```